# Periodic Summation Response. How to separate its Transient and Steady-State Expression?

Tags: laplace-transform, periodic-functions, steady-state

## Background

My question comes from here, it's a response of 1st order LPF RC circuit from an arbitrary periodic input.

> [How to determine the transient response of a circuit to causal periodic inputs?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/452447/116274)

---

## Problem

Suppose if I have input signal with period of $T = 10s$

$\displaystyle u(t) = 2t (\theta(t) - \theta(t - 5)) + 0 (\theta(t - 5) - \theta(t - 10) )$

For t from 0 to infinity, there'll be $1-e^{-sT}$ in the denominator.

[image]

and then the system transfer function

$ H(s) = \dfrac{1/sC}{R + 1/sC} $

In order to find it's output we need F(s) which is a transfer function for one single period response from the input signal. Inverse it. Multiplies it with unit step since it's a causal signal and system. And then time shifted it by $nT$.

$ F(s) = H(s) U(s) $

$ f(t) \theta(t) = $ [image]

$ \displaystyle \begin{align} f(t-nT) \theta(t-nT) &= 2\ \theta(t - nT) \left( RC (e^{-(t-nT)/(RC)} -1) + (t - nT)\right) \\ &+ 2\ \theta(t-5 - nT) \left(  (5 - RC) e^{-(t-5-nT)/(RC)} + RC - (t - nT) \right) \end{align}$

Then from periodic summation properties of laplace transform we get
$ \displaystyle y(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{1-e^{-sT}} F(s) \right] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(t-nT) \theta(t-nT) $

---

Assume if $R = 50k$ and $C = 100uF$, thus time constant of $5s$. This is the plot

> [Sum[2UnitStep[t-10n] (  5 ( e^(-(t-10n)/(5) ) - 1) + t - 10n )     +   2UnitStep[t - 5 -10n] ( (5-5) e^(-(t - 5 - 10n)/(5) ) + 5 - (t - 10n) ), {n, 0, 5}]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B2UnitStep%5Bt-10n%5D%20%28%20%205%20%28%20e%5E%28-%28t-10n%29%2F%285%29%20%29%20-%201%29%20%2B%20t%20-%2010n%20%29%20%20%20%20%20%2B%20%20%202UnitStep%5Bt%20-%205%20-10n%5D%20%28%20%285-5%29%20e%5E%28-%28t%20-%205%20-%2010n%29%2F%285%29%20%29%20%2B%205%20-%20%28t%20-%2010n%29%20%29%2C%20%7Bn%2C%200%2C%205%7D%5D)

[image]

Now if I change the time constant into $20s$. This is the plot if we sum it from n = 0 to 20.

> [Sum[2UnitStep[t-10n] (  20 ( e^(-(t-10n)/(20) ) - 1) + t - 10n )     +   2UnitStep[t - 5 -10n] ( (5-20) e^(-(t - 5 - 10n)/(20) ) + 20 - (t - 10n) ), {n, 0, 20}]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B2UnitStep%5Bt-10n%5D%20%28%20%2020%20%28%20e%5E%28-%28t-10n%29%2F%2820%29%20%29%20-%201%29%20%2B%20t%20-%2010n%20%29%20%20%20%20%20%2B%20%20%202UnitStep%5Bt%20-%205%20-10n%5D%20%28%20%285-20%29%20e%5E%28-%28t%20-%205%20-%2010n%29%2F%2820%29%20%29%20%2B%2020%20-%20%28t%20-%2010n%29%20%29%2C%20%7Bn%2C%200%2C%2020%7D%5D)

[image]

---

## Question

**How to separate its transient and steady state response?** Such as,

$ \displaystyle y(t) = y_{tr}(t) + y_{ss}(t) $

**At what time t such that the transient vanishes?**

**How many period T of input signal does it take for it to be vanished?**

I couldn't find any approach since it's difficult to find when the overlapping magnitude became steady. And that depends on the time constant, which results in asymptotic to 0 as t goes to infinity on each summation term.

Comment: No one answers yet...